# getting index of a multiple line string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Trying to get an integer in a multi-line string with its value same as its index. Here's my trial.

```
table='''012
345
678'''
print (table[4])
```

if i execute the above, i will get a output of 3 instead of a 4.
I am trying to get number i with print(table[i])

What is the simplest way of getting the number corresponding to table[i] without using list, because i have to further use while loops later to replace values of the table and using lists would be very troublesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your string contains whitespaces (carriage return and mabye linefeed) at position 4 (\n in linux, \n\r on 4+5 on windows) - you can clean your text by removing them:

```
table='''012
345
678'''
print (table[4]) #3 - because [3] == \n
print(table.replace("\n","")[4])  # 4
```

You can view all characters in your "table" like so:

```
print(repr(table))
# print the ordinal value of the character and the character if a letter
for c in table:
    print(ord(c), c if ord(c)>31 else "")
```

Output:

```
'012\n345\n678'

48 0
49 1
50 2
10 
51 3
52 4
53 5
10 
54 6
55 7
56 8
```

On a sidenote - you might want to build a lookup dict if your table does not change to skip replacing stuffin your string all the time:

```
table='''012
345
678'''

indexes = dict( enumerate(table.replace("\n","")))
print(indexes)
```

Output:

```
{0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8'}
```

so you can do `index[3]` to get the '3' string

Comment: Might worth while to show the output of `print(repr(table))` to make the example more obvious... I'm not quite sure what the OP is after here, as if having to remove newlines every time to index into it seems umm... odd...

Comment: @jon added visualization

Comment: Depending how often the OP is going to add things as well... doing something like: `indices = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(ch for ch in table if ch != '\n')}` might also be an idea... then `indices['4']` will return the expected value... - but then, again, hard to say

Comment: Need to get that table swapped over so it's ch->index and not index->ch - and to emulate `str.index` make sure it takes the first occurrence as my comment above :)